# Gauss Map under Reparameterization

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm wondering about the effect of reparameterization of the Gauss map. Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a surface element and $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Define the Gauss map to be the normals on the surface:

$$\nu(u_1,u_2)=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2}}{||\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_1}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_2}||}$$

Now if we create a new parameterization $\tilde{f}=f\circ \phi$, then apparently $\tilde{\nu}=\pm \nu\circ\phi$. It makes sense that this should be the result, but I'm unable to get it directly from the definition above.

This specifically pertains to chapter 3 in Kühnel when discussing reparameterization of the shape operator.

Comment: Write out the chain rule for $\frac{\partial\tilde f}{\partial v_1}$ and $\frac{\partial\tilde f}{\partial v_2}$ and take the cross product.